# Outlook Addin : Custom Task pane show/Hide

Tags: c#, outlook, custom-controls

I have created an Outlook add-in. In that I have a custom task pane. If user closes the task pane it wont show to open that again I have to restart the Outlook.
I have searched for that and found the solution in [This Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb608590.aspx). But it creates the button in the Ribbon. That I don't like. I want achieve some thing like:
[image]

Is there any way to control the header control of the Custom task pane?
How can I implement this in my Custom task pane?
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance...!

Comment: Do you use the standard VSTO?? or do you use third party controls?

Comment: I used standard VSTO. Third party controls is not alowed to use for me. In development.